# Trying to understand the proof of the second Hilbert-Schmidt theorem; a theorem on symmetric kernels

Tags: functional-analysis

Currently I'm self studying functional analysis, namely self-adjoint operators. In the text, the author gives the following theorem and proof:

---

> **Theorem A**(*The second Hilbert-Schmidt theorem; a theorem on symmetric kernels*): Let $I=[a,b]$ and $\mathcal{H}:=L_2(I)$. Consider the operator
> $$
> (Kx)(s):=\int_a^bK(s,t)x(t)dt,
> $$
> where $K(s,t)\in L_2(I^2)$. It is know that such an operator is compact. Let $K=K^*$ (meaning that $K(s,t)=\overline{K(s,t)}$). Let $\{e_i(t)\}$ be all orthonormal eigenvectors of $K$ (according to the first Hilbert-Schmidt theorem) and $Ke_i=\lambda_i e_i$. Then,
> $$
> K(s,t)=\sum_{i\geq1}\lambda_i e_i(s)\overline{e_i(t)}.
> $$

*Proof* (leaving out some of the computation details). Let $\eta_i(s,t)=e_i(s)\overline{e_i(t)}$. Then $\{\eta_i\}$ is an orthonormal system in $L_2(I^2)$. Hence the function
$$
\phi(s,t)=\sum_{i\geq1}\langle K,\eta_i \rangle_{L_2(I^2)}\eta_i\tag{1}
$$
exists as an element of $L_2(I^2)$. It follows by computation that $\langle K,\eta_i \rangle_{L_2(I^2)}=\lambda_i$. Therefore $\phi(s,t)=\sum\lambda_i\eta_i$.

Take $x(t),z(t)\in L_2(I)$. By the first Hilbert-Schmidt theorem we know that
$Kz=\sum\langle Kz,e_i \rangle e_i$. Then,
$$
\langle Kz,x \rangle=
\int_a^b\int_a^bK(s,t)z(t)\overline{x(s)}dtds=
\langle K,x(s)\overline{z(t)}\rangle_{L_2(I^2)},\tag{2}
$$
and
$$
\langle Kz,x \rangle=
\langle \sum\langle Kz,e_i\rangle e_i,x\rangle=
\sum\lambda_i\langle z,e_i \rangle\langle e_i,x \rangle.\tag{3}
$$
This can be written in the $L_2(I^2)$ scalar product as
$$
\sum\lambda_i\langle \eta_i,x\overline{z}\rangle_{L_2(I^2)}=\langle\phi,x\overline{z}\rangle_{L_2(I^2)}.\tag{4}
$$
Consequently, for every function $x(s)$ and $z(t)$ in $L_2(I)$ we have
$$
\langle\phi,x\overline{z}\rangle=\langle K,x\overline{z}\rangle\tag{5}
$$
or equivalently
$$
\langle\phi-K,x\overline{z}\rangle=0.\tag{6}
$$
Notice that the set $\{x(s)\overline{z(t)}:x\in L_2(I),z\in L_2(I)\}$ is complete in $L_2(I^2)$. Therefore $\phi-K=0$.

---

My issue is that I don't understand a few parts of this proof; hence, I don't understand the proof. Namely, why does the author introduce $(2)$ and $(3)$, i.e., what are their uses in the proof? It seems that $(4)$ can be obtain independent of $(2)$ and $(3)$, simply by "pushing" the $\sum\lambda_i$ "into" the inner product. I assume their use must be used in obtaining $(5)$, since I'm not sure where $(5)$ comes from either. Lastly, why does the set
$\{x(s)\overline{z(t)}:x\in L_2(I),z\in L_2(I)\}$ being complete in $L_2(I^2)$ imply $\phi-K=0$?

---

**EDIT**:

I've come back to this problem, and after some time I figured out my first few questions. Namely, the questions I had regarding $(2)$, $(3)$, $(4)$, and $(5)$. So I was correct that $(4)$ is obtained independently of $(2)$ and $(3)$, i.e., you obtain it how I mentioned. However, $(4)$ is used to "connect" $(2)$ and $(3)$ to obtain $(5)$ in the following manner:
$$
\langle \eta_i(s,t),x(s)\overline{z(t)} \rangle=
\langle e_i(s)\overline{e_i(t)},x(s)\overline{z(t)} \rangle=
\int_a^b\int_a^b e_i(s)\overline{e_i(t)}\overline{x(s)\overline{z(t)}}ds\,dt.
$$
Thus,
$$
\langle \eta_i(s,t),x(s)\overline{z(t)} \rangle=
\int_a^b\int_a^b e_i(s)\overline{e_i(t)}\overline{x(s)}z(t)ds\,dt=
\int_a^b\left(\int_a^b e_i(s)\overline{x(s)}ds\right)z(t)\overline{e_i(t)}dt
$$
Therefore,
$$
\langle \eta_i(s,t),x(s)\overline{z(t)} \rangle=
\left(\int_a^bz(t)\overline{e_i(t)}dt\right)\left(\int_a^b e_i(s)\overline{x(s)}ds\right)=
\langle z,e_i\rangle \langle e_i,x \rangle.
$$
So we see that
$$
\langle \eta_i(s,t),x(s)\overline{z(t)} \rangle=\langle z,e_i\rangle \langle e_i,x \rangle.
$$
Therefore
$$
\sum\lambda_i\langle \eta_i(s,t),x(s)\overline{z(t)} \rangle=
\sum\lambda_i\langle z,e_i\rangle \langle e_i,x \rangle.
$$
We obtain $(5)$ in the following fashion
$$
\langle \phi,x\overline{z} \rangle=
\sum\lambda_i\langle \eta_i,x\overline{z} \rangle=
\sum\lambda_i\langle z,e_i\rangle \langle e_i,x \rangle=
\langle Kz,x \rangle=
\langle K,x\overline{z} \rangle.
$$